# Erro ao criar projeto android com xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Instalei o Xamarin no VS 2015, tudo normal.
Quando eu vou criar um projeto Android dá o erro

> *Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1*

Pra criar pra iphone ele cria normalmente.

O que pode ser?

Comment: talvez a SDK do android..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848644/2740371